# Get an element of HTML content in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am new in JQuery and having problem in getting element from HTML.

Comment: What problem? What element? What HTML? What have you tried? How does the result you get differ from what you expect? You need to provide a **lot** more details as any reasonable answer (to the question as it stands) is going to end up being a pointer to the documentation for the main jQuery object or a (superficial) rewrite of the same.

Comment: What do you mean by getting element from html? Show us your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use $(this is the parent of element).find(expected element).
just like as

> $(div).find(table)

see this [link](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you need the context part of [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function:

```
// string with HTML content
var content = '<div><p class="myel">Test</p></div>';

// returns '<p>' element
var myEl = $(".myel", content);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#id").html() or $("#id").text();

"#" is used for id 
. is used for class

<div id="id">this is text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is rather vague I'll take a stab at understanding your issue anyway,

You can retrieve any HTML element as an object in `jquery` simply by referencing it in any number of ways that is possible in `jquery`.

**i.e**

if you have a `div` with an `id` of `noodles` ( `<div id="noodles"></div>` ) you can reference it in jquery with something like

```
myHTMLelement = $('#noodles').html();
```

or if you want the html as plain text you can do the following

```
myHTMLelement = $('#noodles').text();
```